# Foreach cycle to not break HTML structure- PHP

Tags: php, html, css, cycle

I have simple HTML / CSS code which should display the 5 most-used browsers used on the website.
HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="browserStat big">
        <img src="{$basePath}/img/browser-chrome-big.png" alt="Chrome">
        <span>36%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="browserStat big">
        <img src="{$basePath}/img/browser-firefox-big.png" alt="Firefox">
        <span>34%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="browserStat">
        <img src="{$basePath}/img/browser-ie.png" alt="Internet Explorer">
        <span>34%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="browserStat">
        <img src="{$basePath}/img/browser-safari.png" alt="Safari">
        <span>34%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="browserStat">
        <img src="{$basePath}/img/browser-opera.png" alt="Opera">
        <span>34%</span>
    </div>                                                  
</div>
```

I also have all the percentages and browsers in my array from the database (browsers are saved as numbers, so for example 1 = IE , 2= Chrome , etc.)

I can easily echo it out like:

```
foreach($borowser as $elem){
  echo '<div>
            <div class="country">'.$elem["borowser"].'</div>
            <div class="number">'.$elem["number"].'</div>
        </div>';
}
```

So basically it looks I have everything which is needed, but I have problem with writing a correct cycle that doesn't break up this HTML / CSS, because it has to always have just 2 browsers with `big` class and 3 with no `big` class.

Can somebody help me to write cycle which will not break this HTML / CSS ?

Comment: Where is your html broken? Could you explain what the problem exactly is?

Comment: What do you mean when you said: *"because it have to always just 2 borowser with "big" part and 3 with "no big" part"*. I have no clue what you mean by *"big" part*. Also how does this harm your CSS and HTML?

Comment: Right if I write cycle like this above, I always get repeat all parts not just first one.  
I need to just check each part once so in general:
Go for first position , check borowser number , display image and % base on it and go for next position and never check first one again.

But what it do is it display everything multiple time or display first one multiple time ...just always  broke HTML in someway

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Sorry it wasn't explained well, i mean that 2 DIVs at start `<div class="browserStat big">`

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($borowser as $elem){
  $is_big = ($i < 2) ? 'big' : '';
  echo '<div class="browserStat ' . $is_big . '">
        <div class="country">'.$elem["borowser"].'</div>
        <div class="number">'.$elem["number"].'</div>
    </div>';
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an extra element in `$elem` just for your classes. Everything you need to then would be

```
foreach($browser as $elem) {
  echo '<div class="'.$elem['class'].'">
          <div class="country">'.$elem["borowser"].'</div>
          <div class="number">'.$elem["number"].'</div>
        </div>';
}
```

Edit: If it's the case, that always the first two need your extra class, go with Ananth' approach.